# CEF initialize returns false

Tags: c#, cefsharp

trying to build an app using CefSharp.Wpf, everything works whenever I use build from Nuget.org, but Cef initialize returns false whenever I add my custom libcef.dll build. I have compiled the same version, used cef-binary to modify the package, but Cef.Initialize fails without any error. Do you know any methods how to debug what is happening in Cef.Initialize and how to catch error or reason why it is not initializing? Here is the code:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
Boolean status = CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error after upgrading to version 53.
Before I was using version 51 without issues.
Initialization code for this version is slightly different

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

// Disable GPU in WPF and Offscreen until GPU issues has been resolved
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");

//Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
Cef.Initialize(settings, shutdownOnProcessExit: true, performDependencyCheck: true);
```

So try older version.